# Adjunct Pair Characterization Applications

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

The characterization of an adjoint pair with triangular diagrams and unit, counit, , has any application in algebra or topology, for example? (does anybody know some exercise where it is easier to use the characterization than the definition of adjoint pair?)

Thank you

Comment: There is a more general notion of adjunction in a 2-category via the unit-counit-zigzag definition; this definition shows that an adjunction is preserved by any 2-functor, which is otherwise not totally obvious. If one is only concerned with adjunctions between categories I think generally the usual homset definition is the cleanest and most natural to work with.

Comment: It's also a natural way of understanding why an adjunction gives rise to a monoid in the category of endofunctors, ie a monad.

Comment: With this description it is easy to see that the adjunction restricts to an equivalence between the two subcategories on which the unit and the counit are isomorphisms.